# Apex CPU time limit exceeded in Batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch

When we are running  the batchApex we are facing "CPU time limit exceeded". Please find my below Batch Apex which we are tried and let me know where we made the mistakes in current Logic.

Batch:

global class OpportunityDays implements Database.Batchable  {

```
Public List<Opportunity> lstOpp;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){  

    String query = 'Select id, Name, StageName, Software_Product_Count__c, CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c, CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c, CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c, CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c from Opportunity Where StageName = \'S8- Closed Won\' AND Software_Product_Count__c > 0 AND ( ((CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c = True AND CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = False) OR (CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c = False AND CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = True)) OR ((CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c = True AND CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = False) OR (CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c = False AND CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = True)) )';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> batch){ 

    lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();

    for(Opportunity objOpp : batch){
        if(objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c == True) {
            objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = True;
        }  

        else{ //if(objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c == False){
            objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = False;
        }

        if(objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c == True) {
            objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = True;
        }   

        else{ //if(objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c == False) {
            objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = False;
        }
        lstOpp.add(objOpp);
    }   

    Database.SaveResult[] dbOppList = Database.Update(lstOpp, false);   
    // System.debug('Update CW ' + dbOppList[].Id);  

    for(Database.SaveResult sr : dbOppList) {
        if(sr.isSuccess()) {
            // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
            System.debug('Successfully Updated OPP ID: ' + sr.getId());
        }       
        else {
            // Operation failed, so get all errors                
            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                System.debug('Users fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
            }
        }           
    }

}    

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: How many record you have in system in Opportunity

Comment: Have you tried running that query in the query editor?  What is the cost of it in the query plan?

Comment: Hi all, we have around 5447 records are available.

Comment: From where you are initiating this batch execution?

Comment: Do you have any code in opportunity trigger? if yes, can you inactive trigger and try executing batch

Comment: @Reshma,  From developer console we are running

Comment: @Shravan Boddula, We don't have any trigger

Comment: What is the batch size? If the batch size is more then iteration over the records may take time, this the error is produced.

Comment: @krishsfdc we are given the batch size 200

Comment: That's the deafult one. Try reducing the batch size, hit and try.

Comment: @krishsfdc,Still same error is getting

Comment: okay. Is there any workflow on Oppty? Seems strange one.

Comment: @krishsfdc ,We don't have any triggers and workflows we have some validation rules are firing   which we are having previously.for that we are using the logic "List<Database.SaveResult> resultList  = Database.update(lstOpp, false);" in my current code after that we are facing CPU time limit exceded.Can you please check my current logic Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please update the code as below

```
    global class OpportunityDays implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>
    {
           global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){  

              String query = 'Select id, Name, StageName, Software_Product_Count__c, CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c, CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c, CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c, CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c from Opportunity Where StageName = \'S8- Closed Won\' AND Software_Product_Count__c > 0';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Opportunity> lstOpp)
    {

    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();        
    for(Opportunity objOpp : lstOpp){

    boolean shouldUpdate = false;
                if(objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c && !objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c) {
                    objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = TRUE;
                    shouldUpdate = true;
                }   
                else if(!objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c && CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c) {
                    objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = False;
                    shouldUpdate = true;

                }

                if(objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c  && !objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c) {
                    objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = True;

                    shouldUpdate = true;

                }   
                else if (!objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c && objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c){
                    objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = False;

                    shouldUpdate = true;

                }                                
    if(shouldUpdate==true)
{
            oppList.add(objOpp);
}
            }
    if(oppList.size()>0)
              List<Database.SaveResult> resultList  = Database.update(oppList, false);
           // update lstOpp;    
        }    

        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
        }  
    }
```

If there is no trigger or workflow on the opportunity, this should work.And please reduce the batch size .

Comment: ,Thanks for your help... we are using  your code with My SOQL : But The problem is Batch is Running fine after completed the batch showing as Total batch = 0 and Batches Processed = 0.But records are not updating. can you please help me on that

Comment: Can you please let me know the number of records under the  query returned and also please put a debug statement under every if condition .Reduce the batch size to 10 records to check what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Hi Preya, Actually what happening in SOQL we are using  below Query, Where StageName = 'S8- Closed Won' AND Software_Product_Count__c > 0 AND ((CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c = True AND CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = False) OR (CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c = False AND CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = True)) OR ((CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c = True AND CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = False) OR (CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c = False AND CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = True)). Problem is Only for 30 days workflows are updating as expecting.don't know why it is not  working to 730 days.

Comment: Using the code i have given above, are you able to update for 30 days workflow without cpu limit error? Please check the condition for 730 days and check if the records exist for the condition

Comment: ,Yes. Your code is working as expected for 30 days without CPU limit error.same logic i have applied for 730 days. Why it is not updating.Can you have a look on this issue.Records are showing around 4300.  Thanks

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: pls find my editable code which we are tried mentioned above

Comment: Are you always getting CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c as false?Are there records with objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c as true?Please check whether there are records that satisfy this condition.As far as logic is concerned,it looks good

Comment: No.We are not getting always CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c  as false.Here we are going to be updating based on formula fields like If formula is true then workflow should be true. Similarly id formula is false Workflow should be false.  this what we are trying.One more thing hear 30 days formula and 730 days formula's are Formula fields which contains the 30 days Formula is :AND(CloseDate >= (Today()-29),CloseDate < (Today()+1),TEXT(StageName) = "S8- Closed Won"). 730 days Formula is :AND(CloseDate >= (Today()-729),
CloseDate < (Today()+1), TEXT(StageName) = "S8- Closed Won" ).

Comment: Whats the issue are you facing now?

Comment: My problem is not updating the 730 days records.we  are good for 30 days records means getting updates was successfully completed . As you know we are using same logic for 730 days also. Why ? Is there any problem my logic ?

Comment: No as far as code is concerned,i don't see any problem in it.
Please check whether there is a record which satisfies the condition ,CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c == true,

Comment: ,When we are running the batch we are facing Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00q1A00000EfPrBQAV; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Can't remove a team member assigned to a split from an opportunity. Can you please help me on this

Comment: are you deleting something in the batch? Did the above issue of not updating for 730  days solve?

Comment: Not yet solved,when we are trying to run the batch we are facing those errors. we are given the batch size 10. What is the errors why am getting? in which scenario we are getting those errors

Comment: Please check if there are any triggers or workflows on opportunity.

Comment: Ok,But we have so many opty triggers are there how to find which one is disturbing this functionality any idea?

Comment: You might have to see in the debug log for the same.

Comment: sure. i will try that .Thanks for your time. Can i ask one question regarding different batch apex?

Comment: We have "Custom Privilege" one custom setting is avalable. Can you please tell me how to include custom settings in my logic . may be this will stop my batch issues, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want your Workflow field to always match your Formula field I don't understand why you have all the if/else stuff going on.  You could simply assign the Workflow field the value of the Formula field.

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Opportunity> lstOpp){ 
    for(Opportunity objOpp : lstOpp){

        objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Workflow__c = objOpp.CW_in_Last_30_Days_Formula__c; 
        objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Workflow__c = objOpp.CW_in_Last_730_Days_Formula__c;

    }
    List<Database.SaveResult> resultList  = Database.update(lstOpp, false);
   // update lstOpp;    
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your suggestions  Actually we are trying to update like 30 Days Formula = True then 30 days Workflow should be true AND  30 Days Formula = False then 30 days Workflow should be False Similarly 730 days also  these all are Picklists. Even though i have tried your logic batch is running but records are not updating.Can you please help me on this,  Thanks

Comment: @Devi If these are all picklists check your Workflow fields to see if they are restricted or not.  If so check to see if the Formula picklists values match exactly the Workflow ones.